# Navigation Bar won't re-hide when switching back to the app from another one and also when I take a screenshot?

Tags: android, kotlin, fullscreen

So I am working on an app which has full screen. The code does work excellently. But when I do switch to any other app and come back to it, the navigation bar and status bar both won't hide. This also happens when I take a screenshot.

Here is a preview:
[image: Preview of problem]

Coming back, here is what I have coded:

```
private fun funcFullScreen() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
    }
```

And I just simply call the function like this `funcFullScreen()`.

What I have tried?

1] `androidFocusableInTouchMode="true"`

2] I also tried adding onWindowFocusChange thing but that gave me another headache, the navigation bar will appear for a second or two when I switch the activities in my app itself. And fixing that seems difficult, I've already tried every possible solution for that available on the internet.

Any way to solve this? By the I'm fine with either Java or Kotlin, my app is made up from both (some activities in Java while others in Kotlin) and both suffer from this issue.

3] Also tried adding the code in onResume, this works when I switch back from another app but not when I take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

So basically I think you are writing this all code in onCreate() method of that activity, When you go to another app, it's activity screen by default show status bar and navigation bar, and you again come back then you don't get a callback in onCreate(), instead, get it in onResume(), So you need to move your code in OnResume() from onCreate() so that it gets called when you come back again to this screen.

Comment: Yeah thanks it did work for me when I switch from other app ... But when I take a screenshot.. then those navigation bar appear again and won't hide back

Comment: I think android enforce status bar visibility while taking a screenshot, Might be android restriction, What you can do, You must be getting a callback after the screenshot is taken, call a method after this, which has the code of hiding status bar and navigation bar, for code refactoring purpose, You can move this code into a separate method, and call it from onResume() and from the callback of screenshotTaken()  method, You can upvote If it helped you.

Comment: Can you please say me how do I detect screenshot taken?

Comment: Actually I have not come across this use case, after googling found there is no definite solution in the market yet, but you can try solution on this link

Comment: There is a library also to detect it
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-ScreenshotDetection

Comment: I will try it once.. I am currently trying to refresh activity